# Multiple Images for Animation Using for loop C#

Tags: c#, animation

I am trying to make a rudimentary, very simple animation function using a simple manager.  The issue is that, as of right now, when the user clicks "Go" on the main form, it will display the first image then jump to the last image.

I have also tried to insert a delay which delays the thing going from 1 to the last frame but it just jumps to the last frame.  I'm utilizing several PNG files in order to make this thing work instead of trying to use a "sprite sheet" which would be a larger pain in the arse I would imageine...

```
Here's the code for the AnimationManager class...

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Animation
{
public class AnimationManager
{

    public PictureBox AnimationBox;
    public float widthX, heightY;
    public string ImageDirectory, ImageName;
    public int frame, maxFrames;
    public int speed; // in milliseconds
    public bool isLooping;


    public AnimationManager()
    {
        AnimationBox = new PictureBox();
        widthX = 0;
        heightY = 0;
        ImageName = null;
        frame = 1;
        speed = 0;
        maxFrames = 0;
        isLooping = false;
    }

    public async void CycleThrough(string ImageDirectory, int FPMS, int maxFrames, bool isLooping)
    {
        for (int i = frame; i < maxFrames + 1; i++)
        {
            ImageName = ImageDirectory + @"\" + frame.ToString() + ".png";
            AnimationBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
            AnimationBox.Refresh();
            await Task.Delay(FPMS);
            switch (isLooping)
            {
                case false:
                default:
                    {
                        frame = maxFrames;
                        break;
                    }
                case true:
                    {
                        frame = 1;
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }
    }


}
}
```

That's as far as I was able to get.  If anyone has any insight or can point me in the right direction to get this to work, that would be awesome.

Comment: as a side note: Dont use switch for little 2 or 3 cases. its slower than if-else. and never use switch on True/Flase.

Answer (score 2):

You had some problems in your code so i write it again and i comment out where you had problem

```
public async void CycleThrough(string ImageDirectory, int FPS, int maxFrames, bool isLooping)
{
    for (int i = frame; i < maxFrames + 1; i++) // frame and maxFrames must not change. counter is i
    {
        ImageName = ImageDirectory + @"\" + i.ToString() + ".png"; // Get the i-th png using counter.
        AnimationBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
        AnimationBox.Refresh();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1/FPS)); // delay in seconds.
        if(isLooping && i == maxframes) // if must Loop and counter is in last iteration then start over
        {
            i = frame - 1; // set the counter to the first frame
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the answer, I went ahead and attempted to do it myself... :)  Thank you for your answers and comments...

This was my final solution...

```
private async void CycleThrough(string ImageDirectory, int FPMS, int maxFrames, bool isLooping)
    {
        this.speed = FPMS;
        for (int i = frame; i < maxFrames + 1; i++)
        {
            ImageName = ImageDirectory + @"\" + i.ToString() + ".png";
            Console.WriteLine(frame.ToString());
            AnimationBox.Refresh();
            AnimationBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageName);
            await Task.Delay(FPMS);
            if (isLooping)
            {
                if (i >= maxFrames) i = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I made an elementary mistake and didn't use "i" that was setup.  Instead I manipulated a bunch of other things that had no bearing on the loop's intent itself.

I agree with the person above - I didn't use a switch in my solution.  It didn't make sense since I only have one conditional that would reset the loop (manipulating i back to 1) if isLooping was true.

This works beautifully so I'll offer this solution to anyone who wants a rudimentary animator for their code :)

Thanks all for your answers and time.